# Sql Query to find out the combined set of unquie stop id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to achieve the following result using TSQL?
Input of data
The table contain three fields: serviceId,stationId, SeqNo
every service can have multiple station, and they are in order by SeqNo
For example, service 1 contains

```
stationId   SeqNo
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
```

Service 2

```
A   1
C   2
D   3
E   4
F   5
```

Service 3

```
A   1
B   2
C   3
```

What I tried to achieve is the result like this

```
stationId   SeqNo
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
E   5
F   6
```

Comment: Why did you select `C 3` if service `2` has `C 2`? Explain the logic you are using to get that data

Comment: That is because C is behind B, at service 1. So basically, the sequence of the stations are fixed, but some service may skip a particular station, what I need is a Superset of all unquie stations in correct order (if possible).

Comment: I don't think this is clear enough. I don't see `C` behind `B` in service one. I see `C` after `B`. It is possible to get the superset of all unique stations, however, the `correct order` is still a mystery. Is it fair to say that the order for a given stationId is taken from the highest value that stationId has among all the services?

Comment: I think you are right, take the highest value among the seqno of a particular stationId will do.

Comment: Note that you will have `D` and `E` both with number `4`. Is that correct? Or maybe you just need unique stations IDs all sorted alphabetically and totally renumbered with their position starting in `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a query as:

```
with CTE as 
(
select min(serviceid) as minserviceid , stationId,max(SeqNo) as maxSeqNo
from T1
group by stationId
),
CTE1 as 
(
select stationId, DENSE_RANK() over(order by stationId,maxSeqNo ) as rnk
from CTE
)
select stationId , rnk as SeqNo from CTE1
```